# Consider a probability measure $P$, Let $Y \geq 0$ have df $F .$ Then show $\mathrm{E} Y=\int_{0}^{\infty} P(Y>y)dy$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

The homework asks us to show the claimed formula above by simple functions and then the full claim by the MCT. Below is what I have done so far:

1. If $Y=a1_A,a>0$
   $$E(Y)=aP(A)$$and

$$P(Y>y) =
\begin{cases}
P(A),  & \text{if $0\leq y <a$} \\
0 & \text{$y\geq a$}.
\end{cases}$$

Hence $\int^\infty_0P(Y>y)dy=aP(A)$

2. If $Y=\sum^n_{i=1}a_i1_{A_i}, a_i>0$, without loss of generality, assuming that $a_1<a_2<...<a_n,$ then
   $$E(Y)=\sum a_iP(A_i)$$ and
   $$P(Y>y) =
   \begin{cases}
   \sum^n_{i=1} P(A_i),  & \text{if $0\leq y <a_1$} \\
   \sum^n_{i=2} P(A_i) & \text{if $a_1\leq y<a_2$}\\
   ...\\
   P(A_n) & \text{if $a_{n-1}\leq y<a_n$}\\
   0  & \text{if $y\geq a_n$}.
   \end{cases}$$
   Therefore $\int^\infty_0P(Y>y)dy=a_1\sum^n_{i=1}P(A_i)+(a_2-a_1)\sum_{i=2}P(A_i)+...+(a_n-a_{n-1})P(A_n)+0=\sum a_iP(A_i)$.
3. If $Y\geq0$,let $Y_n\geq0$ be simple with $Y_n \uparrow  Y$ then,

\begin{align}
E(Y) & = \lim E(Y_n) \text{   by MCT} \\
 & = \lim \int^\infty_o P(Y_n>y)dy \\ 
 & = \int^\infty_o \lim  P(Y_n>y)dy \\
 & = \int^\infty_o  P(\lim  Y_n>y)dy \text{   (*)}\\ 
 & = \int^\infty_o P(Y>y)dy
\end{align}

---

My question is:

1. is my proof correct? The first part is provided by our teacher. I assume his approach is to show the expression of $E(Y)$ and $\int P(Y>y)dy$ is the same. I am particularly not sure about the step where I used (*). My reasoning is that $P$ is $\sigma$-additive, so it is continuous from below.
2. how to intuitively understand equality? In expression, $\int P(Y>y)dy$ are we treating $P(Y>y)$ as another measurable function, and $dy$ simply the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: You reasoning is correct. In addition, continuity from below doesn't need to require that $P$ is $\sigma$-additive.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thank you so much for verifying the reasoning!